# Couchbaselite update operation leads to inconsistent behavior

Tags: java, android, database, updates, couchbase-lite

I am using Couchbase Lite SDK for android and saving an object instance of `MyClass` as a document in the database. `MyClass` has an attribute that stores the date in the `java.util.Date`. During run time, I fetch all the instances of `MyClass` saved in the database and store them in the `ArrayList<MyClass>`. When I insert a new document into the database and read the values from the database to show all the entered instances, the date field saved in the database is retrieved as a `Long` when I next try to fetch the details from the database. The code I use to load the details from the database is:

**Code snippet 1:**

```
for (Field field: fields) {
                field.setAccessible(true);

                if (properties.containsKey(field.getName())) {
                    if ("date".equals(field.getName())) {
                        Log.d("DebugTag", properties.get(field.getName()) + "");
                        long dateLong = (Long) properties.get(field.getName());
                        details.setDate(new Date(dateLong));

                    } else {
                        field.set(details, properties.get(field.getName()));
                    }
                } else if("_id".equals(field.getName())) {
                    details.set_id(document.getId());
                } else {
                    final String msg = "Field " + field.getName() + " not present in document ";
                    Log.e(TAG, msg);
                }
            }
```

You can see that I have added an additional check in case the field is `date`. This works perfectly fine. So, I save a new entry to database and come back to the page where I see all the entries made into the database.

Now, I have implemented a new functionality to update the details of a record in the database. For updating the record I have the following implementation:

**Code snippet 2:**

```
public static boolean updateDocument(Database database, String docID, Map<String, Object> map) {
    if (null == database || null == map || null == docID) {
        return false;
    }
    boolean success = true;
    Document document = database.getDocument(docID);

    try {
        // Have to put in the last revision id as well to update the document.
        // If we do not do this, this will throw exception.
        map.put("_rev", document.getProperty("_rev"));
        // Putting new properties in the document ...
        document.putProperties(map);
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error putting property", e);
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}
```

After doing this when I try to reload the items, it gives me exception while reading the date field in my **Code snippet 1** saying that the `Date` object cannot be typecasted as `Long` and the application crashes. Now, when I again open the application, it works perfectly fine with all the changes to the edited entry reflecting correctly. Can anyone let me know the reason for this? I suspect, until we close the database connection, the changes are not committed to the actual database location and the date field in the updated entry is kept in the cache as the `Date` object in my case.

**PS:** Although, I have found a workaround for this by setting the date as a `Long` object in the payload (**map** in function `updateDocument()` in **Code snippet 2**), it would still be interesting to understand the problem I faced.

Comment: Hey @Swapnil, regarding the issue it should not be crashing though which is concerning.  Seeing that this is reported 2 weeks ago, do you have any further updates or resolutions to share?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this further, this could be reasons related to auto-boxing where long to Long conversion of primitive types to the object wrapper class is crashing the application when trying to save.

Have you tried:

```
long value = Long.parseLong((String)...);
```

More specifically in Code snippet 1:

```
long dateLong = Long.parseLong((String)properties.get(field.getName()));
```